# Dismissing Fragment Dialog onResume

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

I've run into a pretty interesting problem. I attempt to dismiss a Fragment Dialog from within my Activity's onResume method. That is all fine and well until it calls my Dialog Fragment's onDismiss method, which when I call getActivity returns null. Why is this? I suspect it's lifecycle related but after debugging to understand I am still unsure as to why this is happening.

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: There's not really anything to show. In my Activity I am calling fragmentDialog.dismiss(), and then inside the dialog fragment itself I have a onDismissListener, so inside of onDismiss I attempt to get a reference to my activity like so: MainActivity ma =((MainActivity)getActivity()).

Comment: are you calling `super.onDismiss()` inside your implementation of `onDismiss()?

Comment: I am. When my activity gets paused, and I come back and in my onResume I dismiss it is when it seems to have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling `super.onDismiss()` your code will go through the default implementation of `onDismiss()` hosted in `FragmentDialog`. From the [docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/DialogFragment.java) we see that it calls the `dismissInternal()` which in turn removes the `DialogFragment`. By the time the code gets to your implementation of `onDismiss()` the `DialogFragment` is probably already removed, hence `getActivity()` returns `null`.